# SEO : things to consider\implement for your website's content

Tags: seo

lets say i have a website that i am developing...

the site may have wallpapers, question & answers, info (e.g imdb,wikipedia etcetera)

what do i need to do so that when some search engine analyzes a particular page of my website for particular, lets say 'XYZ', it finds 'XYZ', content it finds 'XYZ' content if it present in that page...

please i am new to this so pardon my non-techy jargon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important tips in SEO revolve around what *not* to do:

- **Keep Java and Flash as minimal as is possible**, web crawlers can't parse them.  Javascript can accomplish the vast majority of Flash-like animations, but it's generally best to avoid them altogether.
- **Avoid using images to replace text or headings.**  Remember that any text in images won't be parsed.  If necessary, there are SEO-friendly ways of replacing text with images, but any time you have text not visible to the user, you risk the crawler thinking your trying to cheat the system.
- **Don't try to be too clever.**  The best way to optimize your search results is to have quality content which engages your audience.  Be wary of anyone who claims they can improve your results artificially; Google is usually smarter than they are.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines (like Google) usually use the content in `<h1>` tags to find out the content of your page and determine how relevant your page is to that content by the number of sites that link to your page.